# React Version 18 - How to reset a button to disabled soon as I click cancel on a modal using TextFields?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

New to React.

How to reset a button back to initial state of disabled soon as I click cancel on a modal.

I have this dialog here. Soon as you click a button it will open up this dialog. The dialog has the ADJUST button disabled until you make write text in the input. It will set the adjust state upon onChange. Soon as you click cancel or click out of the modal and go back, the state is still being set as ADJUST as NOT disabled.

How do I make the button disabled when leaving the dialog?

Example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  Dialog,
  DialogContent,
  DialogTitle,
  MenuItem,
  TextField,
} from "@mui/material";

const testDialog = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [adjust, setAdjust] = useState("");

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setAdjust("");
  };

  const handleAdjustments = (event) => {
    setAdjust(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dialog
        fullWidth
        open={props.boxOpen}
        onClose={props.handleClose}
      >
        <DialogTitle>
          Test
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <div>
        
            <div>
              <TextField
                sx={{
                  label: { fontSize: 13 },
                  input: { paddingTop: 1, paddingBottom: 2 },
                }}
                size="medium"
                fullWidth
                required
                id="countProducts"
                label="Count of products"
                variant="outlined"
                onChange={handleAdjustments}
              />
            </div>
        </DialogContent>
        <div>
          <Button onClick={props.handleClose}>CANCEL</Button>
          <Button disabled={!adjust}>ADJUST</Button>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
  );
};
export default testDialog;
```

I expect to always see the dialog button ADJUST as disabled soon as I leave and open the dialog page. if I try to do input in textfield, the button will turn orange. Once I click cancel or I click out of the dialog, the button will go back to disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling `handleClose()` or using the `open` state. If `props.boxOpen` and `props.handleClose` control the visibility, you don't even appear to need a local `open` state.

What you can do is use your local `handleClose()` to modify the `adjust` state and call through to `props.handleClose()`

```js
const handleClose = () => {
  setAdjust("");
  props.handleClose();
};
```

with

```jsx
<Dialog
  fullWidth
  open={props.boxOpen}
  onClose={handleClose}
>
```